# How to resolve "error finding potential wrapper bundle for node" when clGetDeviceIDs called by command-line application?

Tags: macos, opencl

I have a command-line application running on macOS (Monterey, but that's likely irrelevant) that calls a library which uses OpenCL. When `clGetDeviceIDs(..., CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, ..., ...)` is called, during OpenCL initialization a message is printed to standard error saying, in full,

```
2022-02-18 12:31:55.709016+0900 toktx[70551:23725709] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x101a590a0> { isDir = ?, path = '<path to my app>' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
```

This is not being printed by the library but by either the OpenCL implementation or macOS. I'm using the macOS OpenCL framework. The "LS" mentioned in the message is LaunchServices.

Despite this message initialization succeeds however having messages printed to stderr that are not coming from the app or library under test is going to make cross platform testing on CI more difficult.

I do not want to have to create a fake bundle for my command-line application. Is there another way to stop OpenCL/the system complaining?

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding an `Info.plist` directly into the executable binary. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it does allow the program to behave more like an app.

In Xcode, create a new Info.plist file, and then in the Build Settings for your command line app's target, you'll need to set the "Create Info.plist Section in Binary" setting to "Yes", and specify the (local) path to your Info.plist in the "Info.plist File" setting.

I don't think you need [very many keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW4) in this dummy Info.plist file; `CFBundleIdentifier`, `CFBundleVersion`, and `CFBundleShortVersionString` are probably enough.

Obviously, this still doesn't give your executable an actual wrapper bundle, so the error might not go away.

Another option is to simply make the executable a resource in a dummy bundle (New Target -> macOS -> Bundle) for environments where it actually matters, rather than turning it into a full-on app bundle.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP. I would like to follow your second suggestion of creating a dummy bundle as an additional target. Now the bundle shows up under the `products` folder as a target. **How can I make my executable a resource of this dummy bundle?** (notice I am mirroring your words almost exactly because I am new to Xcode and openGL^)