# Xcode boilerplate openGL build produces error: `error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x100a09910>`

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

I am working on compiling a simple openGL program in Xcode on my M1 Mac. When I build, It succeeds, but I get a nasty

```
2022-04-05 09:54:18.959203-0500 opengl[24908:835152] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x100a09910> { isDir = ?, path = '/Users/liamwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/opengl-awawpgevgzpjofbrfmzvucbfrzpp/Build/Products/Debug' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
2022-04-05 09:54:18.959276-0500 opengl[24908:835152] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x100a09910> { isDir = ?, path = '/Users/liamwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/opengl-awawpgevgzpjofbrfmzvucbfrzpp/Build/Products/Debug' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
2022-04-05 09:54:18.959308-0500 opengl[24908:835152] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x100a09910> { isDir = ?, path = '/Users/liamwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/opengl-awawpgevgzpjofbrfmzvucbfrzpp/Build/Products/Debug' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
2022-04-05 09:54:19.019242-0500 opengl[24908:835152] [default] error finding potential wrapper bundle for node <FSNode 0x100a09910> { isDir = ?, path = '/Users/liamwhite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/opengl-awawpgevgzpjofbrfmzvucbfrzpp/Build/Products/Debug' }: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10811 "kLSNotAnApplicationErr: Item needs to be an application, but is not" UserInfo={_LSLine=1579, _LSFunction=wrapperBundleNodeForWrappedNode}
2022-04-05 09:54:19.054172-0500 opengl[24908:835152] Metal API Validation Enabled
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

A potential fix is proposed in [a similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168389/how-to-resolve-error-finding-potential-wrapper-bundle-for-node-when-clgetdevic), but I am new to Xcode and the answer is too vague for me.

Below is my code, if it is of any consequence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);
    
    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = static_cast<char*>(alloca(length * sizeof(char))); // alloca is from C. it allows dynamic stack allocation!
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);
    
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
    
    return program;
}

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    if(!glewInit())
        return 0;
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    
    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };
    
    unsigned int vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    
    std::string vertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";
    
    std::string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";
    
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    
    glUseProgram(shader);
    
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `glfwWindowHint()` *after* `glfwCreateWindow()`?  `glfwWindowHint()` only affects the *next* `glfwCreateWindow()` call and OpenGL 2.1 contexts (the best you'll get on macOS without requesting a Core context) most certainly don't support `#version 330 core` GLSL code.

Comment: @genfault I am new to Xcode and openGL, that said, I don't think that is the cause of the issue I am asking about. Do you know anything that could help me?